# Calculating Banzhaf for large number of voters

Tags: voting-system

I'm calculating governance metrics and Banzhaf power index is one of them. The algorithm requires creating all possible coalitions and if the number of voters is large (i.e. 100, or on my laptop larger than 22) creating a set of of possible coalitions exceeds my computing power. A large enough set would exceed most organizations power.

I'm using this algorithm for creating subsets:

```
function createSubsets(set) {
   var n = set.length;
   var result = [];

 // Run a loop for all 2^n subsets one by obe
   for (var i = 0; i < (1<<n); i++) {
       var item = [];
       for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ((i & (1 << j))) {
               item.push(set[j]);
           }
       }
       if(item.length > 1) // no need for the empty array, and for each voter on his/her own.
          result.push(item);
     }
     return result;
}
```

From looking around it seems like the most efficient. So I'm thinking we should use a subset of all the voters and run on it.

How would you go about it? How would you choose which voters to calculate the Banzhaf on? Simply the top 20 or so, and then calculate the quota of their relative voting powers?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over $2^n$ subsets is likely to get you into trouble no matter how powerful your computer is. Perhaps you should try a more efficient algorithm, e.g. « [Efficient computation of power indices for weighted majority games](https://www.nii.ac.jp/TechReports/public_html/03-006E.pdf) »?